Are で/へ interchangable here?
I am doing my practice questions in my textbook, and I answered the following
デパート（で）プレゼントを買い(に)行きました. - Wrong use ,へ instead
美術館（で）彼に会いました - Correct
カリナさんは日本（で）美術（の）勉強(に)来ました - Wrong use へ
In the first and last sentence my answer key says to use (へ). To be honest that makes sense to me since those are locations. But a previous grammar point in my textbook said we can use で when we do an action at a certain location.. for example
駅で新聞を買いました.
so im just wondering. Can I use で in those sentences instead of へ too?

へ means “to” so it makes sense, whereas で means “at” so it would not work.
EDIT:
If I force myself to parse it as "デパートでプレゼントを買いに" "行きました" then it does sound grammatical to me (you are "going" to perform the action "buy present at the department store"). But IMO most people will parse it as "デパートで行きました" (perform the action "go" at the department store, and the "プレゼントを買いに" adding info to that sentence.
In case of カリナさんは日本で美術の勉強に来ました, I can't force myself to parse it as "日本で美術の勉強に" "来ました" - i.e. came to perform the action "study in Japan". It would always mean "(already being) in Japan, perform the action "come to study art" which is odd and was not what was meant (since you wanted to say you came to Japan, not that you moved whilst already being in Japan).
Maybe the first sentence can (barely) be made to work because デパートでプレゼントを買う is a very common action. For example 大学で勉強に行きましたsounds wrong but not too much. If you say 大学で買い物に行きました, it will always mean you started the journey inside the Uni (maybe you had to walk to a shop inside the Uni). If you meant you went to the Uni from your home to buy something, it will not be taken that way.

hmmm... I thought the first sentence with de means "I went to go buy a present AT the department store"

@BingChilling: Added edit

I guess it's possible, but it's awkward enough that it should be ruled out at this level of study.
デパートへプレゼントを買いに行きました -> you went to the department store to buy presents - fine.
デパートでプレゼントを買いに行きました -> it seems like you want to interpret this like, you went (somewhere unspecified/implied) to buy presents in the department store. But this is really awkward. (I think it sounds awkward even in English.) You want デパートで to modify 買う rather than 行く. This sort of i-stem + に + main verb construction is a collocation, so you can't really put other participants after it, which allows the listener to interpret デパートで as going with 行く instead. But it would be strange to specify a で-marked part for such an i-stem in the first place, and I'm pretty sure it would normally go after the を-marked part even then. Not to mention the conceptual awkwardness: it implies that you might go somewhere else, simply to enable the process of buying things in the department store... ?
Similarly, Karina surely didn't come to some unspecified place for the purpose of studying art while in Japan - how would the act of arriving there, facilitate the study? It makes far more sense to simply say that she came to Japan, to study art.
